# Does C++Builder 6 include a "DEBUG" macro or a similar facility?

Tags: build, c-preprocessor, conditional-compilation, c++builder-6

With GCC it's possible to pass a command-line flag like `-DDEBUG` and then use conditionals like `#ifdef DEBUG`. C++Builder 6 has a built-in notion of "debug mode" vs. "release mode"; is there any way to determine (preferably from within the preprocessor) which mode the application is being built in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In full debug mode, C++Builder also defines a `DEBUG` conditional that can be tested with `#ifdef` statements.  You can see it present in the Conditionals list in the Project Options.

Comment: I found that it defines `_DEBUG` (in BCB6) when in debug mode. Can both be right?